# Choosing specific dataview values from a SQL statement and assigning them a variable VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataview, datarowview

Good morning! I am attempting to create a timelog for a current project, I need to somehow assign a value to the variable 'depart' from a dataview that I've pulled. I'm sorry if this is like another question but I couldn't seem to find something to help my answer. Please note: depart, firstDate, etc. are all declared already.

```
dataview = dba.Query("SELECT Time, Status FROM Timelog WHERE [Date] = '" & firstDate & "' AND USERNAME LIKE '" & AgentList.SelectedValue & "' ")

For Each rowView AS DataRowView in dataview
    DIM row as DataRow = rowView.Row
    If dataview.Find("Departed") Then
    depart = dataview.Find("time"
End If
Next
```

I plan on using the DateDiff function to calculate the hours between a departure and return from lunch, and then lunch and arrival.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to take a value from a grid and put it in a variable? And where is your issue?

Comment: I keep getting the error 'Value of Type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'Date'. I'm confused on how to assign depart to the Time Value from the dataview only when the status is equal to departed.

Comment: I am assuming that `depart` is declared as a `Date` type and `dataview.Find("time")` returns an integer. Could it be returning time as the number of seconds/ticks/etc from midnight? What is "time" in the Timelog table?

Comment: @Steve Depart is declared as a DateTime and dataview.find("time") should be returning a DateTime as well because that's how it is pulled from the DB. It's also returning the time as a DateTime because I've put breakpoints in and checked the dataview table. The "time" is the column name.

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: depart = dataview.Find("time")
Sorry for not being able to explain this better!

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what dba.Query() returns but I assume it is some type of collection, based on the fact you are iterating through it on the next line. Because of that, dataview.find() would NOT be returning a value from a row, but more like the index of the column that has that name.

What you need to do is get the value of the field for the current row of your iteration:

```
depart = rowView("Time")
```

Comment: Although this didn't answer my question, it did give me an idea and helped me understand a rowView more. I now have it working. Thank you!